# Check difference between 2 dates in t-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, date-difference

Best method to check between 2 dates to see if they are within exactly 3 months of each other using T-SQL.

For example if I had these 2 dates below I want to check if `@Date1` is within 3 months of `@Date2` and vice versa.

```
 DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME = '2019-01-15 00:00:00.000'

 DECLARE @Date2 DATETIME = '2018-10-23 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Define 3 months? 90 days? Is Feb 28 2019 three months apart from Nov 30 2018?

Comment: Also define "within exactly 3 months". Within 3 months of each other? Exactly 3 months apart? Something else?

Comment: Unclear as the question is, I'm pretty sure the answer can be found here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes 28/02/2019 and 30/10/2018 is 3 months. Its to the exactly 3 months not 90 days i.e. 15/01/2019 & 15/10/2018 is fine but 15/01/2019 & 14/10/2018 is past.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple statement:

SELECT abs(DATEDIFF(month, @date1, @date2)) <= 3

Comment: This is incorrect according to the explanation provided in OP. Jan 31 and Apr 1 are 3 months apart according to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
  DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME = '2019-01-15 00:00:00.000'

  DECLARE @Date2 DATETIME = '2018-10-23 00:00:00.000'

  SELECT dateadd(MONTH, 3,@Date1 ) >= @Date2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
    DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME = '2019-01-15 00:00:00.000'

    DECLARE @Date2 DATETIME = '2018-10-23 00:00:00.000'



   SELECT CASE WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, @date1, @date2)) <= 90 THEN 'Inside 3 Months' 
ELSE 'Outside 3 months' END
```